# How to use hero animation between TabBar views?

Tags: dart, flutter

I had three routes and many hero animations in my project. Now, I want to use a route with three tabs to swipe easily between pages, But these changes disabled all of my hero animations. I used `TabBarView` and `TabController` like all of the other examples of material `TabBar` implementation.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution for using hero animations between the pages of a  `TabBarView`?

Answer (score 4):

In order for a `Hero` animation to work, you need to be navigating between pages on a `Navigator` stack. Unfortunately, a `TabBarView` doesn't use a `Navigator` to switch between tabs, so we're going to have to implement our own custom tab view widget that does use a `Navigator` in order to make hero animations work.

Let's start by making a page route that mimics the sliding transition animation of a `TabBarView`:

```dart
/// A [PageRoute] that mimics the transition animation of a [TabBarView].
class TabPageRoute extends PageRoute {
  final TabController tabController;
  final Widget child;

  TabPageRoute({
    required this.tabController,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Color? get barrierColor => null;

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return child;
  }

  Animation<double> applyEasing(Animation<double> animation) =>
      CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.ease);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    final isAnimatingNext = tabController.index > tabController.previousIndex;

    // Animates the page when it moves between the middle of the screen and the
    // right of the screen.
    final rightMiddleTween = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: isAnimatingNext ? const Offset(1, 0) : Offset.zero,
      end: isAnimatingNext ? Offset.zero : const Offset(1, 0),
    );

    // Animates the page when it moves between the middle of the screen and the
    // left of the screen.
    final middleLeftTween = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: isAnimatingNext ? Offset.zero : const Offset(-1, 0),
      end: isAnimatingNext ? const Offset(-1, 0) : Offset.zero,
    );

    return SlideTransition(
      position: rightMiddleTween.animate(applyEasing(animation)),
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: middleLeftTween.animate(applyEasing(secondaryAnimation)),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // If you want the state of each of your tab pages to be preserved when that
  // page isn't visible, keep this set to true. Otherwise, set it to false.
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  // This seems to be the default transition duration that TabBars use.
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 300);
}
```

Now let's make a custom tab view that uses a `Navigator` and our new `TabPageRoute` to switch between tabs:

```dart
class HeroTabBarView extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> pages;

  // Just like a normal TabView, you need to either have a parent
  // DefaultTabController or pass a TabController.
  final TabController? controller;

  const HeroTabBarView({
    super.key,
    required this.pages,
    this.controller,
  });

  @override
  State<HeroTabBarView> createState() => _HeroTabBarViewState();
}

class _HeroTabBarViewState extends State<HeroTabBarView> {
  late TabController _controller;
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final resolvedController =
        widget.controller ?? DefaultTabController.maybeOf(context);

    if (resolvedController == null) {
      throw FlutterError(
        'No TabController for ${widget.runtimeType}.\n'
            'When creating a ${widget.runtimeType}, you must either provide an explicit '
            'TabController using the "controller" property, or you must ensure that there '
            'is a DefaultTabController above the ${widget.runtimeType}.\n'
            'In this case, there was neither an explicit controller nor a default controller.',
      );
    }

    _controller = resolvedController;
    _controller.addListener(_switchPage);

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.removeListener(_switchPage);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _switchPage() {
    // Use the route's name as the index of the page to switch to.
    _navigatorKey.currentState!.pushReplacementNamed('${_controller.index}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use a nested Navigator so that switching tabs involves pushing a
    // new page onto a Navigator stack without changing the general
    // navigation state of your app.
    return Navigator(
      key: _navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: '${_controller.index}',
      // This is required in order to make Hero animations work in a
      // nested navigator.
      observers: [HeroController()],
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) => TabPageRoute(
        tabController: _controller,
        child: widget.pages[int.parse(settings.name!)],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now we can use `HeroTabBarView` with a `TabBar` just like we would use a normal `TabBarView`. Make sure that you either have a parent `DefaultTabController` that wraps both your `TabBar` and `HeroTabBarView` or that you pass your own `TabController` to your `TabBar` and `HeroTabBarView`.

```dart
class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: const TabBar(
              // Change these to whatever icons you want.
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: const HeroTabBarView(
            // Replace with the pages you want for your tabs.
            pages: [PageOne(), PageTwo(), PageThree()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Result

[image: Screen recording]

#### Interactive Example

You can check out this code in action with [this interactive example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5a08d4f20c9ecd40f06b288cd341ee36) on DartPad.

Comment: Yep you fix it !

(Funny things during the night I think about this same solution and I make it this morning ahha)

Anyway, you win the bounty well done mate ;) !

Comment: @Eng Thanks, glad I could help! Make sure to accept the answer if it solves your question :).

Comment: @Erfan Jazeb Nikoo

Answer (score -1):

1. 

```
Create Two Screens with a Hero Widget:

Start by creating two separate screens (widgets) that you want to transition between using the TabBar.
Wrap the common widget that you want to transition with the Hero widget on both screens.
// Screen 1
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen 1'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Screen2(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'hero-tag',
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Screen 2
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen 2'),
      ),
      body: Hero(
        tag: 'hero-tag',
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 300.0,
          width: 300.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enter code here
Implement a TabBar:

Wrap your screens with a DefaultTabController or any other method you
```

prefer for implementing a TabBar.
Ensure that both screens are available as tabs.

```
class TabBarExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2, // Number of tabs
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TabBar Example'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Screen1(),
            Screen2(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because `TabBarView` doesn't use a `Navigator`, meaning that navigating between `TabBarView` pages won't fire `Hero` animations, which fire when the page on the `Navigator` stack changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).